# Python - Plotting text file returns 'ValueError: invalid literal for float():'

Tags: python, numpy, text, matplotlib

So I have this text file that i'm trying to plot. It has 5 columns of simulated data and im trying to plot each column from 2 - 5 to the 1st column.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('SampleData.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

returning
`ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Anyway I can fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with open('SampleData.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')

x = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
y = [float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

It seems that it's a type coercion problem. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Tried it, still returns a 'ValueError'.

Comment: Sorry you actually helped with my question, the actual error is now `ValueError: could not convert string to float:  `. So i'll see what i can do with that. Thank you.

Comment: Does your data have a header? If so, eliminate it and read the rest in.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the data you obtained from the text file is **string**. That is to say, before you plot it, you first need to convert it into **float** type. It can be easily done by **float()**.

```py
x = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
y = [float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]
```

Make sure that the format of input data is legal for **float()**.

For `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`, it depends on your text file. There may be some unformatted data in it which cannot be directly converted into **float** type.

Answer (score 0):

Try typcasting your split to an integer before using the add_subplot

Comment: More comment than answer

Comment: Agree.  I'm still trying to figure out the way this works.  I thougt by hitting the up arrow on your post I was saying your answer was better.  My bad.